# Create a linked list from a 2D array in Java

Tags: java

If I have a 2D string array (or int array), how can take this and create a linked list out of it?The linked list can be a 2D linked list or regular linked list and it doesn't matter if the list is double, single, circular or multi-linked lists.

Comment: Hi @ttucker34..i'll suggest you share some sample for more clarity

Comment: (1) create instance of LinkedList, (2) iterate over array and put each element into LinkedList instance. If that is not what you wanted then please [edit] your question and clarify problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use two nested `for` loops or Java 8 Streams.

For a 2-dimensional array of primitives:

```
final int[][] arr = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9, 10 } };
final LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> list = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .map(x -> Arrays.stream(x).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
System.out.println(list);
```

For a 2-dimensional array of objects:

```
final String[][] arr2 = {
        {"a","b"},{"c"},{"d","e","f"}
};
final LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> list2 = 
        Arrays.stream(arr2).map(x -> new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(x)))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
System.out.println(list2);
```

Comment: It's a matter of opinion as to whether that is "simpler" than a simple nested for-loop.